# Does MySql perform search on partition in parallel?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

For example there is a table with 2 partition on column which has 2 values: 'A' and 'B'. Consider a select:

```
select * from my_talbe where my_column in ('A','B'); //other where conditions here
```

Does MySql performs this select in parallel? Or it select from first partition then second?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not (currently) do any query from a single connection with any parallelism.  That includes `IN()`, `OR`, `PARTITIONed` tables, 'UNION', etc.

Exceptions:  Some background I/O in InnoDB is done in parallel.  "Parallel replication threads" are optionally available in Slaves, but that is kinda like having multiple connections.